# How to load Second controller on click of button from FirstController in AngualrJS

Tags: angularjs

Question on loading second controller on click of button

- Can I use controller inside another controller (like my example
  below)
- On click of "showMore" div, is it possible to call another
  controller to load content in dialog ?

**page1.jsp**

```
<div ng-controller="FirstController">
  <div ng-click="showMore()">Text 1</div>
  <div ng-click="showMore()">Text 2</div>
</div>

<!-- my modal dialog -->
<script type="text/ng-template" id="SecondController.html">
 <div ng-controller="SecondController" style="top:20px;left:300px;position:absolute;">
   <div ng-repeat="content in Contents">{{content}}</div>
 </div>
</script>
```

page1.js

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp',[]);
app.controller("FirstController", function($scope, $templateCache){

  $scope.showMore = function(){

     $templateCache("SecondController.html");
     // what should be done here to open Second Controller 
     // and populate "Contents" div
  }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Can I use controller inside another controller (like my example below)

Yes, the way you have set up your template will allow you to use a separate controller for the modal subsection. It might however be better to go about it in another way.

- On click of "showMore" div, is it possible to call another controller to load content in dialog ?

Angular controllers rarely directly interact, so information is mostly passed through services or broadcasts depending on your need. In this case, you need to populate the Contents variable in either the parent scope (FirstController) or Secondcontroller.Contents. In the latter case, you might need to change the ng-repeat reference to SecondController.Contents.

I would suggest that the easiest way to go about the intended functionality as I understand your intent, is to use a modal library like f.e. the Angular UI: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ or ngDialog https://github.com/likeastore/ngDialog .  Unless you have a specific reason not to, both of these projects have good examples of using modal dialogs that you can adjust to your own needs in your controllers.

Comment: Thanks. I am using $modal (ui.bootstrap.modal) from http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to "load" the controller explicitly. Angular loads an associated controller when `ng-controller` directive is $compiled, or when route is used.

For you cases, you can do:

In the `FirstController` controller, declare a boolean on the scope:

```
$scope.showMore = false;
```

In the view:

```
<div ng-controller="FirstController">
  <div ng-click="showMore = true">Text 1</div>
  <div ng-click="showMore = true">Text 2</div>
</div>

<div ng-if="showMore" ng-include="'SecondController.html'"/>
```

You could also use states angular-ui-router (as suggested by another answer), but I feel that states are better suited for well-defined app states, and not so much for dialogs, which you want in your question.

P.S.

Also, the way you named your template - i.e. "SecondController.html" - suggests that your are thinking of controllers and views as coupled. They should not be. The controller should not care about whether it has a view/html associated with, what it is, and whether that HTML is displayed or not. All the controller should care about is managing the ViewModel "state" of the small part of the app that it controls, and marshaling data between ViewModels and Models.

Answer (score 0):

You can have nested controllers, but the markup content will not be loaded from a template unless you do ugly things like `<ng-include src="{{ somevar }}"` (dont do that)

To actually have real nested routes, you'd be better off using something like:

- angular-ui-router: [https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router]
- angular route segment: [http://angular-route-segment.com/]